# images duplicate in jquery carousel

Tags: jquery, arrays

Please see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2C8fy/29/

The trouble I'm having is that sometimes when you click the decrease button and then switch to the increase button or vice-versa, some of the slides on the end get duplicated. The images that you see at the top are the images that get stored in the array. They get stored just like that and then the user can cycle through the array. Why are some of the slides duplication when you switch buttons?

My theory is that it's a problem with the way I'm using the array, but I can't seem to pin point it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wrong variable use. Replace:

`var newImgSR = imgArr[a].clone();` with  `var newImgSR = imgArr[b].clone();` in `function slide_img_right()`

Comment: Thanks... That works exactly how I need it. Can't believe that's all there was to it. I was going through and trying all this complicated stuff, all I had to do was change one letter.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried some complicated things too before I realized what was the mistake :))